# PHP after sending response send another link

Tags: laravel, return, response

one of my system needs to implement such a ways, that after getting on my link i replied a

```
return response('OK', 200);
```

or

```
return response('Unauthorized', 401);
```

Now, i need to implement such a ways that after returning ok response, i need to go through another link. How am i supposed to implement that? I am using php laravel. I am kind of unsure how these will work. Will i get to go to another laravel route for that or any other ways?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
return response()->setStatusCode(200, 'OK');
```

and

```
return response()->setStatusCode(401, 'Unauthorized');
```

For redirection you can use `redirect()` function.Or if response ok then you can go for `redirect` another `route` what you want.

```
return redirect('user/login')->with('message', 'Login Failed');
```

Comment: Thanks vaia, but as i asked after sending 'OK' response i need to send out another api link , how am i supposed to add after return on this function?